# How do you log Into the TigerGraph account on the server?

Tags: database, nosql, tigergraph

I've just installed TigerGraph on my server, but I don't know how to access the TigerGraph account that it created?

Answer (score 1):

By default when you install TigerGraph the default username and password will be tigergraph. You can try the following from the account you used to install TigerGraph on.

Regular user with NO sudo access:
`su - tigergraph (password is tigergraph)`

User with Sudo access:
`sudo bash`
`su - tigergraph`